# Cordova pruning error for android config.xml

Tags: android, xml, cordova, build, widget

When I run `cordova build android` I get the following error:

`Error: Pruning at selector "widget" from "/Library/WebServer/Documents/app/app-name/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml" went bad.`

I have tried reinstalling the Android platform several times, but no luck.

I am using Cordova 6.1.1, Android 5.1.1 and have updated Android Studio to the latest Dev tools and SDK.

Anyone else experienced this problem? I can't find anything similar online.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone else experiences this issue, I fixed it by:

- Removing all platforms.
- Removing all plugins
- Update Cordova
- Add all platforms
- Add all plugins

Build Android should run successfully.

Comment: Worked for ios, too.  
Remove all plugins (on mac) with this command:  
    `cordova plugins list | awk '{print $1}' | xargs cordova plugins rm`